# How are built in Android applications so small?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, media

I've been working on a relatively small Android game app recently and after much optimization I can only get it down to use 20-30mb of ram. I was curious as to how some Google or Android apps can use so little ram. For example, on my S4 the music app rarely, if ever, uses more than 6mb of ram, even though it plays music and displays many album artworks.

Comment: there is no way anybody can tell you anything unless you provide what you have done so far

Comment: Probably they use native code. JVM on start reserves a lot memory for heap. Question is how do you mange your resources?

Comment: harvey, I'm not really looking for help right now but was just more curious as to what techniques those guys use.

Comment: @MarekR they use java code(mostly) native code is used for situations that require more processing speed

Comment: are you asking about ram or the size of the app ?

Comment: ram. As is displayed in the Active Apps application.

Answer (score 1):

The android [developers website](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) has a dedicated page for this issue. For memory optimizations I can think of the following points:

1. Re-use objects
2. Avoid static variables as easy work around as they cannot be garbage collected
3. Optimize your **Bitmaps** images contribute to a lot of RAM usage
4. Dont hold on to objects after they are not needed